Convert an array of complex numbers to a generic type container in Rust
I'm implementing a mathematical vector in Rust with a generic type K that should be used for f32 and Complex<f32>.
However, for some reason, the implementation seems to support only f32 type.
This is the code from the vector.rs file:
pub use core::fmt;
pub use core::ops::Neg;

pub use num::complex::Complex;
pub use num::Num;
pub use num::Zero;

impl<K> Vector<K>
where Vector<K>: std::fmt::Display, Matrix<K>: std::fmt::Display,
K: Copy + Clone + num::Num + num::Float + std::ops::AddAssign
+ std::ops::SubAssign + std::ops::MulAssign + std::fmt::Display
+ std::ops::Neg<Output = K> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Vector {
            values: Vec::new(),
            rows: 0
        }
    }
    
    pub fn from(arr: &[K]) -> Self {
        Vector {
            values: arr.to_vec(),
            rows: arr.len()
        }
    }

    pub fn from_vec(vec: Vec<K>) -> Self {
        Vector {
            values: vec.clone(),
            rows: vec.len()
        }
    }

    pub fn print(&self) {
        println!("{}", self);
    }

    pub fn add(&mut self, other: Vector<K>) {
        self.vectors_have_equal_length(other.clone());
        for (a, b) in self.values.iter_mut().zip(other.values.iter()) {
            *a += b.clone();
        }
    }

    pub fn sub(&mut self, other: Vector<K>) {
        self.vectors_have_equal_length(other.clone());
        for (a, b) in self.values.iter_mut().zip(other.values.iter()) {
            *a -= b.clone();
        }
    }

    pub fn scl(&mut self, scalar: K) {
        for el in self.values.iter_mut() {
            *el *= scalar.clone();
        }
    }
}


The main.rs file:
fn main() {
    let _ = panic::catch_unwind(|| {
        let complex_numbers = [
            Complex::new(1.0, 1.0),
            Complex::new(1.0, -1.0)
        ];

        let mut vec: Vec<Complex<f32>> = complex_numbers.to_vec();

        let mut t = Vector::from_vec(vec);

        println!("{}", t.norm());
    });
 }

The error message states that the compiler expects a vec based on the Vector::from_vec() function I previously showed:
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:68:28
   |
68 |         let t = Vector::from_vec(vec);
   |                 ---------------- ^^^ expected `Vec<f32>`, found `Vec<Complex<f32>>`
   |                 |
   |                 arguments to this function are incorrect
   |
   = note: expected struct `Vec<f32>`
              found struct `Vec<Complex<f32>>`
note: associated function defined here
  --> src/linear_algebra/vector.rs:79:9
   |
79 |     pub fn from_vec(vec: Vec<K>) -> Self {
   |            ^^^^^^^^ -----------



Your code is incomplete and missing portions may be the reason. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Also, please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Thank you, will avoid posting images of error messages

Please also [edit] this question to include the error as text. We're after all not trying to answer this question just for you, but trying to create a repository of questions that future visitors can read and learn from.

Side note: there's absolutely no reason to clone the vector in from_vec

@Sebastian Redl It does not compile without clone, because vec does not implement the copy trait...

That's because you still need the original vec around to get its length so you can store it in the other variable. But you could either just get the length into a local ahead of time, or just get rid of that field entirely since it is entirely redundant, always being the same as the length of the internal Vec.

@Sebastian Redl, I get what you mean, thanks a lot

linear_algebra.rs:
pub use core::fmt;
pub use core::ops::Neg;

pub use num::complex::Complex;
pub use num::Num;
pub use num::Zero;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone)]
pub struct Vector<K> {
    values: Vec<K>,
    rows: usize
}

impl<K> Vector<K>
where Vector<K>: std::fmt::Display,
K: Copy + Clone + num::Num + std::ops::AddAssign
+ std::ops::SubAssign + std::ops::MulAssign + std::fmt::Display
+ std::ops::Neg<Output = K> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Vector {
            values: Vec::new(),
            rows: 0
        }
    }
    
    pub fn from(arr: &[K]) -> Self {
        Vector {
            values: arr.to_vec(),
            rows: arr.len()
        }
    }

    pub fn from_vec(vec: Vec<K>) -> Self {
        Vector {
            values: vec.clone(),
            rows: vec.len()
        }
    }

    pub fn print(&self) {
        println!("{}", self);
    }
}

impl std::ops::Mul<Vector<f32>> for f32 {
    type Output = Vector<f32>;

    fn mul(self, _rhs: Vector<f32>) -> Vector<f32> {
        let mut a: Vector<f32> = Vector::new();
        for el in _rhs.values.iter() {
            a.values.push(*el * self);
            a.rows += 1;
        }
        a
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for Vector<f32> {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> Result<(), fmt::Error> {
        for n in self.values.iter() {
            write!(fmt, "[")?;
            write!(fmt, "{}", (n * 100.).round() / 100.)?;
            write!(fmt, "]")?;
            write!(fmt, "\n")?;
        }
        println!("The vector has {} rows.", self.rows);
        Ok(())
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for Vector<Complex<f32>> {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> Result<(), fmt::Error> {
        for n in self.values.iter() {
            write!(fmt, "[")?;
            write!(fmt, "{}", n)?;
            write!(fmt, "]")?;
            write!(fmt, "\n")?;
        }
        println!("The vector has {} rows.", self.rows);
        Ok(())
    }
}

impl std::ops::Mul<Vector<Complex<f32>>> for Complex<f32> {
    type Output = Vector<Complex<f32>>;

    fn mul(self, _rhs: Vector<Complex<f32>>) -> Vector<Complex<f32>> {
        let mut a: Vector<Complex<f32>> = Vector::new();
        for el in _rhs.values.iter() {
            a.values.push(*el * self);
            a.rows += 1;
        }
        a
    }
}

impl Vector<Complex<f32>> {
    pub fn norm(&self) -> Complex<f32> {
        let mut sum = Complex::<f32>::zero();
        for el in self.values.iter() {
            sum += el.powf(2.);
        }
        return sum.powf(0.5);
    }
}

and main.rs:
use std::panic;
use crate::linear_algebra::Vector;
use crate::linear_algebra::Complex;

pub mod linear_algebra;

fn main() {
    println!("\n\x1b[31;1;4mThe Norm\x1b[0m\n");

    let _ = panic::catch_unwind(|| {
        let complex_numbers = [
            Complex::new(1.0, 1.0),
            Complex::new(1.0, -1.0)
        ];

        let vec: Vec<Complex<f32>> = complex_numbers.to_vec();

        let mut t = Vector::from_vec(vec);
        t.print();
    });
}

The problem was the presence of num::float in linear_algebra.rs, since Complex does not implement the num::float trait.
However, the error message appeared after I cut out half of the code.
Edit: I have a file matrix.rs calling functions of the linear_algebra.rs file.
And in matrix.rs I didn't add the line:
use super::Complex;
